# Android fast running sqlite query

Tags: android

I'm using a database for searching and facing following issue.

When new search string comes I need to block the previously executing database query.

How can I do this?

Comment: what's the size of your database?

Comment: my table contain 7000+ records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot stop a query as the request to the database is synchronous. But you can try to exclude the request to the database into a thread so you can stop the thread when a new request should be done.

Anyway it would be a good idea to do the query in a thread oder AsyncTask so you don't block the UI when querying the database.

Comment: Can i use lucene for searching

Comment: Mh, I don't think so, although Lucene is a Java library it is not designed to run on mobile devices like Android where resources are limited.

Comment: Found the following, perhaps it might help: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/601329551a87e601?pli=1

Comment: I have used lucene(3.0.2) and work for me ,it create single file and search in that file,i don't know how to convert my query in to lucene query because it contain join,union  . can you suggest some other feasible solution for my problem

Comment: I don't know what data you store in the database. But perhaps it might be better to keep the database on a server instead of storing it locally. So you could keep the search logic on the server using Lucene.